# How to make autorun stop at the max value?

Tags: manipulate

What should be configured in Manipulate in order to make autorun stop at the max value of a variable and not go back to its initial variable?

Comment: Better use `Animate` with `AnimationRepetitions`

Answer (score 1):

Just to put an answer here, following up on @belisarius's apt suggestion to use Animate instead, and in particular to use the `AnimationDirection` and `AnimationRepetitions` options:

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[{-Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tmax},
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][(650 - 350) #3 + 400] &),
  PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[90], CapForm[None]},
  PlotRange -> 2, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
  ],
 {tmax, 1*^-3, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 AnimationDirection -> Forward, AnimationRepetitions -> 1
]
```

[image: fan animation]

Comment: @Hermano, if you think that my answer above adequately solves your problem, would you consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it?

Comment: After exporting this plot into an .avi file the animation goes back to the initial value. How to stop animation after exporting?

Comment: @K.J. Wouldn't that depend on the media player you are using?

Comment: I don't think it is related to the media player. Can you try exporting the above animation into an .avi file and play it? Here's what I'm getting after running `Export["animation.avi",%]` in Mathematica 10.2: [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61qy2dor2g2ittd/animation.avi?dl=0)